# Correlation analysis for more than two binary (categorical) variables in R

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have a 996x12 database that collects categorical variables. All of them are dummy variables (1,0). One of the variables indicates whether or not they disclose on the environment and the other eleven variables indicate different sectors whether or not it belongs to that sector.

My intention is for R to return me a table where the correlation between whether they disclose or not and the sector it belongs to is calculated. In other words, compare a variable with the other eleven variables.

How would it be done?

I have tried to test the `cor ()` function but I get missing values NA.

```
       DISCL Energy Materials Industrials Consumer.discretionary Consumer.staples .......
DISCL   1                       
Energy  NA  1                   
Materials   NA  NA  1               
Industrials NA  NA  NA  1           
Consumer.discretionary  NA  NA  NA  NA  1       
Consumer.staples    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   
Health.care NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
Financials  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
Information.technology  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  
Communication.services  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Have you read the `cor` documentation for the `use` argument? You might want to try something like "pairwise.complete.obs". If you're only interested in the first row you can subset the output like `cor(...)[1,-1]` which excludes the first column since the correlation between the same variable is always one.

Comment: It goes great like this!